# Enabling programmatically multilingual support in Drupal

Tags: drupal, internationalization

I'm building a module that creates a content type ( http://yaremchuk.ru/blog/how-create-content-type-drupal-7-programmatically). I would like to programmatically enable multilingual support with i18n but I don't find how ?

It's the same as manually go To Publishing Options -> Multilingual support -> "Enabled, with translation" but it has to be done in module installation.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution I found :

in hook_install :

```
variable_set('language_content_type_<bundle_name>',TRANSLATION_ENABLED);
```

and in hook_uninstall :

```
variable_del('language_content_type_<bundle_name>');
```

No trace of this in documentation.
Thanks for the really good documentation drupal ! ;)

Hopes my hours spent on it will help someone...

Comment: Yes, you helped me a lot!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me `TRANSLATION_ENABLED` didn't work while `1` did:

```
variable_set('language_content_type_<bundle_name>', 1);
```